# Error creating Bean with name 'xmlViewResolver'

Tags: spring-boot

i am building a small web application with spring boot and theirfore i do not have an xml files as all configurations are handled by spring boot capabilities , however i decided to add an xmlViewResolver and gave the first priority. With that said i keep getting the following error:

Please Assist me in anyway possible , thank you

Configuration file is as follows:

```
package com.aubrey.demo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsps/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }


    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource resource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        resource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public XmlViewResolver xmlViewResolver(){

        XmlViewResolver resolver = new XmlViewResolver();
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/WEB-INF/Spring/views.xml");
        resolver.setLocation(resource);
        //xmlViewResolver().setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }
}

views.xml is as follows :
```

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

        <bean id="welcome" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
            <property name="url" value="/WEB-INF/views/xml_welcome.jsp" />
        </bean>


    </beans>

</beans>
```

Home controller is as follows:

```
package com.aubrey.demo.controllers;

import com.aubrey.demo.data.entities.Project;
import com.aubrey.demo.data.entities.Sponsor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String goHome(Model model){

        Project project = new Project();
        project.setName("First Project");
        project.setSponsor(new Sponsor("NASA", "555-555-5555", "nasa@nasa.com"));
        project.setDescription("This is a simple project sponsored by NASA");

        model.addAttribute("currentProject", project);

        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'xmlViewResolver' defined in class path resource [com/aubrey/demo/WebMvcConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [WEB-INF/Spring/views.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-INF/Spring/views.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist